# How can I convert a bag to an array of numeric values?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to turn the following schema:

```
{
  id: chararray,
  v: chararray,
  paid: chararray,
  ts: {(ts: int)}
}
```

into the following JSON output:

```
{
  "id": "abcdef123456",
  v:    "some identifier",
  paid: "another identifier",
  ts:   [ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ]
}
```

I know how to generate the JSON output, but I can't figure out how to turn the `ts` attribute in my Pig Schema to just the array of numeric values.

The number of items in the `ts` bag is known, but they all have the same schema `(ts: int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig doesn't support array kind of datatype, one option could be you can try something like this.

**input**

```
1       1       100     {(1),(2),(3)}
2       2       200     {(4),(5)}
3       3       300     {(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)}
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (id: chararray, v: chararray,paid: chararray,ts: {(ts: int)});
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id,v,paid,CONCAT('[',BagToString(ts,','),']') AS ts;
STORE B INTO 'output' USING JsonStorage();
```

**Output:**

```
{"id":"1","v":"1","paid":"100","ts":"[1,2,3]"}
{"id":"2","v":"2","paid":"200","ts":"[4,5]"}
{"id":"3","v":"3","paid":"300","ts":"[1,2,3,4,5,6]"}
```

Comment: That's what I figured. I ended up just going with the standard bag.